# Cloning stuck on checking source

Tags: git, repository, clone, sourcetree

I'm using sourcetree and I plan to clone a repository from our github but my sourcetree got stuck on "checking source" I wonder whats the problem and how could I resolve it. I already tried using the embedded git but still it does not work

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looks like no one was able to help with this issue. I found that getting stuck on "checking source" generally means an issue with your Git client. This can boil down to a few things.

1. **Basic configuration**
   Are you using system/pre-existing Git, and it was removed or configured incorrectly? You may need to fix this, or switch to the "embedded Git" that SourceTree can install.
2. **Credential failure**
   Double-check to make sure all of your credentials are correct (or delete them entirely to re-enter). SourceTree keeps authentication information in Tools > Options > Authentication.
3. **SSH keys/client configuration**
   By default you'll find SourceTree attempting to communicate via SSH, this may or may not work with some hosts, if you do not have them trusted or "known". You can test getting around this by using HTTP(S) to clone your repository.

SourceTree doesn't make it very easy to observe when issues arise like this, just the ominous "checking source" that I was plagued with as well. If you haven't already figured it out or nuked it from orbit, hopefully this helps!

Comment: In my case, I had to try to SSH with PuTTY first to get the host added to the list of known hosts.  After that SSH-based cloning worked as expected.

Comment: In the version 3.3.9 of SourceTree you don't get option to provide Git installation. It just two options System and Embedded. What sucks is the fact that when I click on Embedded, it download the same Git Portable and just keeps at the location convenient to SourceTree. it would have been better if they provided option to let user provide location of the Git installation on the system. I want to provide location of Portable Git and don't want SourceTree to litter my system by downloading and putting one more copy of the PortableGit somewhere is AppData/locals whatever windows directory.

Answer (score 2):

For me (Setup: new Mac / MacOS V 10.15 / SourceTree / Github), the issue was that Apple's **Command Line Tools for XCode** were not installed. Installing them worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on a Mac

1. Open the terminal and try git clone git@github.com:willemmulder/someRepo.git
2. Mac wanted to install XCode tools for me to make the git command work
3. After installation, perform the git clone again
4. Mac will ask you to trust the remote IP. Accept.

Now Sourcetree also works.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by checking connection to the host and then adding the host to known hosts when asked. Try calling this with your host or just manually add the host to known hosts file (.ssh/known_hosts)

ssh -T git@gitlab.example.com

Answer (score -1):

It could may well be the fact that the DNS server is not responding with the hostname you provided. Try using the actual IP.

**Try :**

```
ssh://whoami@10.2.0.5/pathto ->/...
```

**Instead of :**

```
ssh://whoami@unresolved.host.org/pathto ->/...
```

Answer (score -1):

First make sure you have loaded your private keys into Pageant, and then try again.

If still have trouble, try to use PuTTY to SSH into the git server hosting the repo. You might receive actually useful errors. Resolve those errors then try again to clone the repository via SourceTree. (Thanks for the comment Jake)